# How to extract file from AVD

Tags: android, sqlite, debugging

I saved a file in my AVD "local disk". Using "File Explorer", i can see the file, it's size and other info, but i cant open it and see whats inside... I also can't drag it, Command+C/V or right click and see options...
basically, its locked inside there...
So, how can I extract it to the desktop or something like that?

Details:

- Using eclipse Luna
- Latest android SDK
- the file is not a txt, its a ".sqlite"
- Developing on MAC OSX Mavericks (latest)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In DDMS perspective -> File Explorer, on upper right there are two icons for pushing and pulling any files from the emulator/avd device. Copy/paste or drag/drop does not work. Please see below, highlighted in red box.

[image: ddms push pull file]